# Send message from extension to GNome desktop application

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gtk, firefox-addon, gnome

I want to make a Firefox / Chrome extension that sends messages to a GNome application made in GTK. I have read something about D-Bus. But I am not clear if it is possible to use that API from a Javascript extension. Is there any method to send messages between browser extensions and GNome API?

Comment: Write a separate utility and run it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API.

Comment: I thought that this way of building apps and that API was deprecated. I confused NAPI with this.

So, to see if I understand it, I have to do:

1º An extension that sends messages to the Chrome APP
2º That my Chrome App handles requests to D-BUS
3º That my GTK App reacts to this message that comes from the Chorme App

This is so?

Comment: There's no need for a chrome app. You will write a separate utility and your extension will use nativeMessaging API to launch it and then communicate.